# Find text height from size and font

Tags: javascript, function, fonts, height, measure

I need a function that does the exact same thing as ctx.measureText(string).width, but with the height of the string. I was quite surprised when I found out that ctx.measureText(string).height doesn't exist. Seems strange that there'd be one for width but not height...

(Please don't use jQuery)

Comment: I bet there already is such function on stackoverflow. This question was definitely asked.

Comment: Care to send a link? Because I certainly couldn't find anything applicable to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab this with the `clientHeight` attribute of an element.

```
const p = document.querySelector('p');

function findHeight(element) {
    return element.clientHeight;
} 

console.log(findHeight(p));
//returns paragraph height in px
```

Comment: It isn't an element though. It's just text being drawn to a canvas using fillText with a given string, px font size, and font (not monospace).

Comment: Ah, I see. That's harder :) Maybe check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816071/calculate-exact-character-string-height-in-javascript