# Trying to create an html box around the letters rendered on the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am trying to measure the real height of the text rendered on my webpage, and then wrapping the text inside a box with no whitespaces. I used the method to calculate height provided by markE in this post [Calculate exact character\string height in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816071/calculate-exact-character-string-height-in-javascript). However when I draw the box around the letter, the box's initial position is at the same position as where the letter's span element starts. Is there a way that the box starts from the real position at which the letter actually starts. [The red box is the html element - letterBox which I want to start from where H letter starts not where the span for letterElement starts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pFbm.png)

My code looks like this:

```
function measureCustomTextHeight(fontSizeFace, customText) {
    var width = 1000;
    var height = 60;
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var text = customText;
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = fontSizeFace;

    var m = ctx.measureText(customText);
    var textWidth = m.width;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillText(text, 0, 40);
    ctx.restore();

    // Get the pixel data from the canvas
    var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,width,height).data,
        first = false, 
        last = false,
        r = height,
        c = 0;

    // Find the last line with a non-transparent pixel
    while(!last && r) {
        r--;
        for(c = 0; c < width; c++) {
            if(data[r * width * 4 + c * 4 + 3]) {
                last = r;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Find the first line with a non-transparent pixel
    while(r) {
        r--;
        for(c = 0; c < width; c++) {
            if(data[r * width * 4 + c * 4 + 3]) {
                first = r;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If we've got it then return the height
        if(first != r) return [last - first, textWidth];
    }

    // error condition if we get here
    return 0;
}
```

```
for (let letter of text) {
        const letterBox = document.createElement("span");
        letterElement = document.createElement("span");

        if (letter !== ' ') {
            const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(letterElement);
            const fontSizeFace = computedStyle.getPropertyValue("font");
            var currLetter = letter;
            var dimensions = measureCustomTextHeight(fontSizeFace, currLetter);
            var textHeight = dimensions[0] + "px";
            var textWidth = dimensions[1] + "px";

            letterElement.textContent = letter;
            letterBox.appendChild(letterElement);
            letterElement.style.display = "inline-block";

            letterBox.style.height = textHeight;
            letterBox.style.width = textWidth;
            letterBox.style.position = "relative";
            measurable_content.appendChild(letterBox);
            letterElement.classList.add("letter-element");
            
            letterBox.classList.add("letter-box");
            letterBox.style.border = "1px solid red";
            letterBox.style.display = "inline-block";
           
        } else {
            letterBox.innerText = letter; // Add a non-breaking space character
            measurable_content.appendChild(letterBox);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably not. That space is part of the glyph that forms the character. It's meant to be there to separate one character from the next or the line above.